# How can I search the comments on Instagram?

Tags: search, instagram, comments

I'm looking for something akin to https://www.youtubextras.com/ but for Instagram feeds. I want to search the comments in all of the threads posted by a specific user.

I know there is a phrase uttered by someone in some thread on Paul Seller's Instagram feed of:

> brass countersunk heads called holding the blade

Typing that phrase into the search field only returns random gibberish.

So, I'm looking for a way to search all comments for a phrase, like I should be able to do with Google, DuckDuckGo, etc.

I tried https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/%22brass%20countersunk%20heads%20called%20holding%20the%20blade%22/ but it says "that page is not available" even when I'm logged in.

Pick any feed/post/whatever-they-call-it such as https://www.instagram.com/p/B6SWLvLJ5aO/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link and scroll down. Then hit + sign button to expand the comments and then again click links such as `View replies (8)` to expand replies one by painful one (and that is very tedious and so a non-starter). Then and only then are you able to type CTRL-f to search forward to find some text, such as what is pointed to by the arrow below:

[image]

So how do I search for that comment especially if I didn't already know where that comment was made (e.g., I recall something about ?  Is it not possible?  If not, then why not?